# Cordova Android not allowing to open whitelisted intent to fb-messenger

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I have an Ionic Cordova app for android which has a button to facebook messenger:

```
<a href="https://m.me/my-fb-page" target="_blank"><img src="assets/images/messenger.svg" /></a>
```

When tapped, nothing appears on the screen. I keep receiving this error through logcat:

```
CordovaWebViewImpl: Blocked (possibly sub-frame) navigation to non-allowed URL: intent://user/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/?intent_trigger=mme&nav=discover#Intent;scheme=fb-messenger;package=com.facebook.orca;end
```

I have cordova-plugin-whitelist installed.

Content of config.xml:

```
    ...
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <allow-intent href="fb-messenger:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <allow-intent href="fb-messenger:*" />
        ...
```

I have tried a number of options for allow-intent, access and allow navigation.

*The issue is not specifically related to facebook messenger, I have problems with opening other external (payment) apps as well*

Comment: Does the link `https://m.me/my-fb-page` (and the resulting error message) depend on what apps are installed for the user? What are other apps this can be tested with?

Comment: This is the link to Facebook Messenger, it should open in the FB Messenger app if installed/browser if not installed. I have one other app that doesn't open, which should be opened through a frame displayed by the payment provider we are using: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.inthepocket.bcmc.bancontact&hl=nl
I can't test this one specifically because it's opened through the payment providers' link. Since <allow-intent href="*" /> is working for neither one I assume the issue is with the plugin configuration.

Comment: Trying to reproduce this, so created an app with only `<a href="https://m.me/my-fb-page" target="_blank">Facebook Messenger</a>` and installed Facebook Messenger. Android asks me if I want to open the link with Chrome or Messenger, if I choose Messenger it opens the app as expected. What am I missing? Can you maybe put a minimal reproduction app on GitHub?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `<allow-navigation href="*" />` you are telling your app to navigate to every url, that prevents any `allow-intent` from working as it will try to navigate to it instead of launching the intent.